# Display additional informatin in the tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have the following highcharts graph

https://jsfiddle.net/deemgfay/

and I am trying to display the "Consum Test" values in the tooltip but without adding them to the series. I just want to add `Consum (l/100km)`
`Total Consum (l)` to the series. Is that possible with hightcharts? Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter). Here I append to tooltip info based on index of current series from index of required extra array.

```
formatter: function() {
  var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
  var reqpoint = 0;
  $.each(this.points, function() {
    var reqpoint = this.point.index
    s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
      this.y.toFixed(2) + 'm';

    if (this.series.index == 1) {
      s += '<br/>Test Consum (l): ' + extraData[reqpoint] + 'm';
    }
  });


  return s;
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ttyddsb/1/) demo

Answer (score 2):

You can set the extra series to be hidden and ignored in legend:

```
  visible: false,
  showInLegend: false
```

Then use tooltip `formatter` function (`useHTML` must be enabled) to display points from all series in the shared tooltip regardless of their visibility:

```
  formatter: function() {
    var html,
      originalPoint = this.points[0];

    // header
    html = "<span style='font-size: 10px'>" + originalPoint.x + "</span><br/>";

    // points
    originalPoint.series.chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
      var point = series.points.find((p) => p.x === originalPoint.point.x);
      html += "<span style='color: " + series.color + "'>\u25CF</span> " + series.name + ": <b>" + point.y + "</b><br/>"
    });

    return html;
  }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/1oggzsx0/

**API references:**

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML

Comment: What is `p`? and where is `p` defined?

Comment: Point from the `series.points` array. It's passed to the arrow function as an argument.

Comment: I have used your solution but is there a way to display the number as `2492,79` also instead of point --> comma and two digits after the comma?

Comment: I have used the numberFormater as the following `html +=  '<span style="color:' + series.color + '">\u25CF</span>' + series.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(entry.y,2,',','.') + '</b><br/>';` :) and it works